# Android BLE MTU size, has anyone sniffed it?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Doing some across platform research into the parameters around BLE on Smartphones.

I have iOS devices so have sniffed the ATT_Exchange_MTU_Req/Rsp for iOS.

Has anyone done the same for Android and got a value?

Comment: And what is the value of ATT_Exchange_MTU_Req on iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldnt get the MTU exchange packet while sniffing. But i have found in code :

#define GATT_MAX_MTU_SIZE     517

https://github.com/tieto/external-bluetooth-bluedroid/blob/master/stack/include/gatt_api.h

Comment: Interesting thanks - so was there no use of ATT_Exchange_MTU_Req (when sniffing), if not I don't know how android what to uses for the MTU?

Comment: Currently when trying to connect between two Android devices (one peripheral, other central) I see a following line in logs: `BluetoothGatt: onConfigureMTU() - Device=55:FC:8A:0C:7D:18 mtu=517 status=0` although I did not call `requestMtu` myself. This means that Android itself tries to negotiate maximum possible ATT MTU size, but in any case the MTU request is initiated by client side, no matter if Android or iOS. The peripheral side just accepts or rejects it, and in case of rejection both sides continue using the default size (23, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

ATT_MTU is defined as the maximum size of any packet sent between a client and a server.

A higher layer specification defines the default ATT_MTU value.

If the client's or server's MTU value is not the default value then the client and server exchange the maximum size of a packet that can be received using the Exchange MTU Request and Response PDUs. Both devices then use the minimum of these exchanged values for all further
communication.

Answer (score 1):

The MTU size to transfer data always varies with the capacity of the peripheral. You can always request to increate the MTU size and transfer more bytes.

Default MTU is 23 bytes